# How do I interpret this operation?

Tags: real-numbers, binary-operations

This question has to do with operations and exploring their characteristics. I have just learned how to extract info from an operations table (what is the identity, inverse, etc.), but this question is presented in an unfamiliar way and I am not sure how to find the answers to the two questions that are given.

$$
a*b = 2a + 3b
$$
I am being asked to "find $3*4$" and whether or not the operation $*$ is commutative. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you confused? If you could specify we could help. Here is an example for your question: $1*1 = 2(1) + 3(1) = 5$. To show that it is (non)commutative, I suggest that you try to prove or disprove that $a*b = b*a$

Answer (score 2):

In order to check whether the operation $*$ is commutative, you need to determine whether
$$
a * b = b * a
$$
for all $a$ and all $b$ in the real numbers.  In other words, you need to figure out whether
$$
2a + 3b = 2b + 3a
$$
for all real $a$, $b$.
This could go one of two ways.

*If it's TRUE,* then you should be able to show that the left hand side is the same as the right hand side just using algebra.

*If it's FALSE,* then you just need a **counterexample**.  In other words, you just have to find some real number $a$ and some other (possibly the same?) real number $b$ such that
$$
2a + 3b \ne 2b + 3a.
$$

Comment: In regards to the first part of the question, is it asking me to plug in 3 for a and 4 for b?

Comment: Yes.  Once you've evaluated $a*b$ for values $(a,b) = (3,4)$, you could also calculate $4*3$ and see if they're equal.  If not, then you have answered the second question as well.

Comment: Perfect. So that means I get 2(3) + 3(4) = 6 + 12 = 18. The operation is not commutative because 2(4) + 3(3) = 8 + 9 = 17!

Comment: That's right.  By the way, you ought to select an answer so that the question shows up as "answered".  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be confused by the notation $a*b$, which in computing would mean the product, but in this case is just an arbitrary operation, defined by the formula $2a+3b$ . Putting it in a table is hard if it is meant to be defined for all reals: that makes the table so big! Once you understand the definition you should have no trouble following Sammy Black's advice.